# R: Separate String Without Delimiter (like Fixed Width in Excel)

Tags: r, split

The dataset looks pretty much like this

[image: Dataset]

I searched around but found only the function that needs a delimiter. I managed to import the file to R successfully with two columns.

Then I want to separate DATE column into "Year", "Month", and "Date." So I want to have 4 column in total. And this is where I got stock. The column doesn't have usual "/" or "-" that usually come with the date format.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It IS delimited by `\t`. You can tell by copying a portion of an excel file and running it as a string in R.

Comment: Hi I just realized that I have not been clear. 

I wanted to separate the DATE column in to "Year", "Month", and "Date."

The date is stored in YYYYMMDD format. But it just doesn't have usual "/" or "-" to separate.

Comment: You could try `read.fwf` (i.e. use fixed width instead of delimiter). For example you would use `c(4,2,2,10)` (the last one would need to be large enough to cover all digits of the price)

Comment: `as.Date('19981201', '%Y%m%d')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @alistaire has shown, you can convert what you have to an R recognised date format with (replace the single character string in the below with your column vector `df$DATE` to work on the entire data frame):

```
date <- as.Date( '19981201', '%Y%m%d' )
date
[1] "1998-12-01"
```

From there, you can separate out your year, month, and day as you please.

```
year <- format( date, "%Y")
year
[1] "1998"

month <- format( date, "%m" )
month
[1] "12"

day <- format( date, "%d" )
day
[1] "01"
```

Of course, you could also skip the date step, and just split the first 8 characters into 3 shorter strings (as @warmoverflow has suggested), but I'd recommend the above as probably better in practice. Mostly because you'll be best using the date format for things like sorting and plotting, so it would be a good idea to use it along the way too.

IN RESPONSE TO YOUR ANSWER/FOLLOW-UP-QUESTION:

Notice in the console output in step 3, the column vector is labeled as class `int` (integer). You probably need to make sure it's being fed to `as.Date` as character. It looks like that's what you tried to do in step 4, but by surrounding the vector reference in quotations, you pass the character string "v1$DATE", which R has no idea what to do with. Instead:

```
v1$date_v2 <- as.Date( as.character( v1$DATE ), format = "%Y%m%d" )
```

Comment: Thank you rosscova! It almost worked.
For some reason, the original code gave " unexpected string constant in "v1$date_v2 <- as.Date(as.character(v1$DATE ),format  "%Y%m%d"""

So I modified a bit to...

v1$DATE <- as.character(v1$DATE) #First step

Then

v1$date_v2 <- as.Date(v1$DATE, "%Y%m%d") # and yes it worked!

I'd guess " = " is needed? 

But in any case, thank you helping solve this issue. :) I appreciate your patience. :)

Comment: Ah yes, a typo, my bad. `=` is definitely necessary there.